# Why does my Net::HTTP.post_form timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app controller I am posting to the api of the app on the same machine. I have build this out to handle the posting the data to the url:

```
url = "http://172.16.155.165:3000/api/jobs"
params = {
  :input => "original/video.h264",
  :output => "new/video.mp4",
  :preset => 'h264'
}

jobResults = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(url), params)
```

This works great when I run this code through rails console but when I use it in my controller it gives me this error after loading for a minute or so:

```
Timeout::Error in SeminarsController#create
Timeout::Error
```

Once the timeout happens the data is actually posted and the api does what it should. It is like it is hanging until it times out then posts the data. The controller never goes beyond this step though. It should write the response body to a file with `jobResults.body` which would work fine if it didn't time out. If I write this into rails console it outputs the response immediately. The api will never take a whole minute to respond.

Am I doing something to cause this to happen? How can I make it work right?

**edit:**
This is the code for `create` in `app/controllers/api/jobs_controller.rb`:

```
def create
  job = Job.from_api(params, :callback_url => lambda { |job| api_job_url(job) })
  if job.valid?
    response.headers["X-State-Changes-Location"] = api_state_changes_url(job)
    response.headers["X-Notifications-Location"] = api_notifications_url(job)
    respond_with job, :location => api_job_url(job) do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_path }
    end
  else
    respond_with job do |format|
      format.html { @job = job; render "/jobs/new"}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ideally you should remove the long running process (yes this is long running process) into background job. Remember that when many users start updating the videos, this process will show down for many reasons (like bandwidth, API acceptance rate etc). `Rake::Timeout` always pops out if the process passes the threshold. It is actually designed to abort requests that are taking too long to respond. And, it is not raised in `console`.

> How can I make it work right?

Move it to the background job. Or you can explictly increase the rake timeout interval by doing something like this

```
# config/initializers/timeout.rb
Rack::Timeout.timeout = 30  # seconds
```

But i suggest not to do this. This `rake-timeout` helps in debugging. Mainly people use in heroku with newrelic.

Comment: I actually set the timeout to 500 and it still timed out. I was just doing it for testing. The console executes this in under a second but the app can't do it in 500. I think there is something else holding my app up. I just don't know what it could be. Running this in the background is ideal. I will look into the right way to do that. Thanks for the help. I think I may just run a system call with something like `curl -d ...` in backticks and just work around not being able to use the returned value.